# Does use of a dictionary count as commercial use

Tags: copyright, licensing, terms-of-service, commerce

Does use of a dictionary on a website count as commercial use if I use its translations **manually** when writing some document that is used in business? Moreover, if there is a note in the website's Terms of Service like this one *You may not copy any part of our services*, is using the dictionary considered as copying?

Comment: Are you just using the dictionary to manually translate a few words? Or are you using an automated script that uses the website to translate your documents?

Comment: Hello! I would use the dictionary only for manual translation. This could, however, include multiple sentences being translated. I have also edited the question.

Comment: With respect to "You may not copy any part of our services" I would say you are not doing that (for me that implies copying the server code), but for the other part, I think more detailed knowledge of the terms of use would be necessary.

Comment: Whether something is used manually or is automated, doesn't decide whether its use is commercial. Commercial use is when you use a product or service for financial gain, although 'non-commercial' can be intended to mean 'personal' use. *"I use its translations manually when writing some document that is used in business."* If you are using the dictionary as a tool for your business, then it is commercial use.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What do you think about the second part of the question?

Comment: Well, what if I consider the use of a dictionary as education? I mean, I am learning a meaning of a word that I want to use. It is not that I use the dictionary to provide someone a service for which I get paid, or that I use the dictionary so that I build my own dictionary and by this advertising my company. What do you think about that?

Comment: If you copy/paste a word from the dictionary into your document, that is copying. The question says "when writing some document that is used in business". That's "commerical use" but if you want to argue your way around that, or whether you think it is unreasonable, it's up to you. The dictionary writer has given you their product *for nothing* and that is their condition of use. You can choose to *pay for* a dictionary and use it as you please, although that too, may have T & C.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you again. Let's get back to the "copying" part. Do you consider that I violate the ToS if I make a translation of a word and put the translated word into a document with respect to the statement I've posted?

Comment: If the document is used for business purposes, yes. If you copy/pasted a word, phrase or translation from the dictionary, yes. If you copied it by sight, letter by letter, yes. Copyright existed before copy/paste and photocopiers.

Comment: The service I want to refer to is Google translate. It is backed by Google's Terms of Service. Under the section _Software in Google services_ in the last sentence you can find (part) of the statement. Do you think do I violate the ToS if I use Google translate the way I have described?

Answer (score 1):

> Does use of a dictionary on a website count as commercial use if I use
> its translations manually when writing some document that is used in
> business?

Probably, although the determination is made on a case by case basis considering all of the facts and circumstances.

> Moreover, if there is a note in the website's Terms of Service like
> this one You may not copy any part of our services, is using the
> dictionary considered as copying?

It is still copying, but it is copying with express permission to do so from the presumed copyright holder (assuming that the copyright holder is the owner of the dictionary website). If the website is infringing on the dictionary copyright owner's copyright, so are uses of the website, notwithstanding the website's terms of service, although the person using the website may not qualify as a willful infringer subject to extra penalties for willfulness in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If the website clearly indicates it is not for commercial use then you can not and should not be using it for profit.

It's like me saying; "I will sell your manual translations for more than you do and advertise it differently". Would you consider this fair on you?

If it is open source with no real 'owner' like public comments on Facebook making the newspapers etc then have at it but if someone's specifically asking you not to do it, it's probably because they have a small server (and they have to pay or build server space) which costs them maintenance costs. If everyone uses it then it will just make it harder for the developer to maintain and that might not be what they want to do everyday. So professional consideration at a minimum I'd say.